# How do I prevent XSS in direct access to AJAX/JSON APIs?

Tags: xss, ajax, json

In my rich client, I escape user-provided data before rendering to prevent XSS.

The data comes from the server unescaped. That is necessary for application logic, e.g., avoiding  situations where I mistakenly check   `"O&amp;Donnell"==="O'Donnell"`

Yet an attacker can send the user a link to direct `GET` access to the underlying JSON API; or the user might stumble upon it. This enables XSS.

How do I prevent this? CSRF tokens?  Setting content-type to plaintext or JSON and not HTML? Some other approach?

Comment: how would a link to a json file enable XSS? text pages don't execute anything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Setting content-type to plaintext or JSON and not HTML?

If the API returns JSON, then you should the content type to `application/json`. Apart from just being correct, this will also stop any XSS issues. If a user navigates directly to an API endpoint in their browser, the browser will just show the raw JSON and not try to render any HTML or run any scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You might send the data from the API base64 encoded, then base64 decode it in the client before processing. Anyway I strongly recommend properly checking and validating untrusted data on server side too:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1):

As Andres mentioned, if the application communicates over JSON, make sure the Content-type is set to application/json and not text/html.